# How to check if any tuples exists for a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to check how many tuples from a list of tuples exists in another list of string and I want all of the tuples associated to the particular string as well.

Example:

```
A = [["is", "a"],["is", "going"],["to", "the"]]

B = ["This is a bat", "Adam is going to the school"]
```

I want the result in terms of which tuple exist in which string.
**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
["is", "a"] exists in "This is a bat"

["is", "going"] and ["to", "the"] exists in "Adam is going to the school"
```

I have tried the below code, but it only gives all of the tuples which exists in list B

```py
A = [["is", "a"],["is", "going"],["to", "the"]]
B = ["This is a bat", "Adam is going to the school"]
matching = [s for s in B if any(x in s for x in A)]
```

**EDIT:**
Another approach tried

```py
A = [["is", "a"],["is", "going"],["to", "the"]]
B = ["This is a bat", "Adam is going to the school"]
    for i in range(len(B)):
        flag = False
        keywords = ""
        for a in A:
            if a[0]+" "+a[1] in B[i]:
                if(keywords == ""):
                    keywords = a[0]+" "+a[1] 
                else:
                    keywords = keywords + ", " + a[0]+" "+a[1] 
        print(keywords)
```

This approach works fine, can it be more optimized ?

Comment: what is the desired output in your example ?

Comment: print all of the tuples from A for each item in B, which exists in B

Comment: What does it mean for `["is", "a"]` to exist in a string? Do the words have to appear in that order? Can there be other words between them? Can they be inside other words, e.g. "is" within "this"?

Comment: Have to be in the same order, with no words in between. Also not within other words

Comment: To amplify @AlexHall `'a'` is `in` `"Adam is going to school"` -- it's the third letter. You'll need to tokenize the words if you only want to match words.

Comment: I have updated another approach which works, but can it be made more optimal

Comment: `all([word in "This is a bat" for word in ["is", "a"]])`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

A = [["is", "a"], ["is", "going"], ["to", "the"]]
joined_A = [" ".join(a) for a in A]

B = ["This is...a bat!", "Adam is going to the school"]

for s in B:
    print(s)
    normalised = " ".join(re.findall(r"\b\w+\b", s))

    for a, joined in zip(A, joined_A):
        if joined in normalised:
            print(a)
```

Output:

```
This is...a bat!
['is', 'a']
Adam is going to the school
['is', 'going']
['to', 'the']
```

Comment: Can it be optimized, it takes long on larger lists

Answer (score 0):

You could use ' '.join() to merge the list from A, then see if it is in the string in B:

```
from collections import defaultdict

matches = defaultdict(list)
for match_string in A:
    for string in B:
        if ' '.join(match_string) in string:
            matches[string].append(match_string)
```

Output:

```
{
    'Adam is going to the school': [['is', 'going'], ['to', 'the']],
    'This is a bat': [['is', 'a']]
}
```

Comment: Can it be optimized, it takes long on larger lists

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
from re import search

A = [["is", "a"], ["is", "going"], ["to", "the"]]
B = ["This is a bat", "Adam is going to the school"]

p_A = ["\\s".join(i) for i in A]
matches = [(s, [A[i] for i, e in enumerate(p_A) if search(e, s)]) for s in B]
for string, patterns in matches:
    print("%s exists in \"%s\"" % (" and ".join("[%s]" % ", ".join("\"%s\"" % s for s in p) for p in patterns), string))
```

**Output:**

```
["is", "a"] exists in "This is a bat"
["is", "going"] and ["to", "the"] exists in "Adam is going to the school"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from io import StringIO

A = [["is", "a"], ["is", "going"], ["to", "the"]]
joined_A = [" ".join(a) for a in A]

B = ["This is a bat", "Adam is going to the school"]

def tokenizer(text):
    return text.split()

vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range = (1,2), tokenizer = tokenizer)

for string in B:
    vec.fit_transform(StringIO(string))
    wordlist = []
    for word, prev in zip(joined_A, A):
        if word in vec.get_feature_names():
            wordlist.append(prev)
    print(f"{wordlist} exists in {string}")


#Output
[['is', 'a']] exists in This is a bat
[['is', 'going'], ['to', 'the']] exists in Adam is going to the school
```

I'm using sklearns CountVectorizer to create lists of all words in the string, then check whether our words are there or not.

I used @Alex Hall joining of words in A since you wanted them to be considered a pair.

We normally wouldn't have to define the function tokenizer, but since sklearns CountVectorizer automatically removes some words like "a" even with stop words turned off we needed to define it here.

ngram_range in our count vectorizer changes how many consecutive words are considered unique. If we left it at 1, it would only be 1 word. 1,2 makes it a most 2 words. You will have to increase the number 2 to be as large as your longest list in A. If all your combos of A are 2 words then you will want to set it to (2,2) to increase speed.

Finally we just loop around the strings. We use `get_feature_names` to pull all the different strings from B, then check if A is there or not. Then finally print the answer.